# Trying to understand expected value in Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, probability

I'm having trouble understanding a lecture slide in my school's machine learning course

[image]

why does the expected value of Y = f(X)? what does it mean

my understanding is that X, Y are vectors and f(X) outputs a vector of Y where each individual value (y_i) in the Y vector corresponds to a f(x_i) where x_i is the value in X at index i; But now it's taking the expected value of Y, which is going to be a single value, so how is that equal to f(X)?

X, Y (uppercase) are vectors

x_i,y_i (lowercase with subscript) are scalars at index i in X,Y

Comment: If X represents a scalar, Y represents a scalar. If X represents a vector, Y represents a vector. So depending on the context of the discussion, vectors or scalars, both meanings are correct in their respective contexts.

Comment: @JamesPhillips can you explain why it's correct? what is it doing

Comment: Let's say that we are talking about the equation " y = m*x + b", and I want to know the value of y when x=5. That would be a single, scalar value and if we both understood this everything would be OK. If we were instead discussing a vector or array of values for x such as [1,2,3,4] the y would also be a vector, and if we both understood this in our discussion that would also be OK. So long as we both agree on whether the context of our discussion was regarding vectors or scalars, we can communicate our ideas without any problem.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I believe X and Y are vectors, x_i and y_i are the scalar values at index i, sorry if that wasn't clear. Can you explain to me why is the expected value of Y equal to f(X), so precisely what does E(Y) = f(X) mean ?

Comment: I have not seen the notation E(Y) = f(X). Perhaps E is for Expected, that might make sense.

Comment: I think some of the confusion goes away if you understand the expected value of a vector E(Y) as another vector whose elements are the expected value of the individual random variables. It's not a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion here. First let's start with definitions

## Definitions

1. Expectation operator E[.]: Takes a random variable as an input and gives a scalar/vector as an output. Let's say Y is a normally distributed random variable with mean Mu and Variance Sigma^{2} (usually stated as: 
   Y ~ N( Mu , Sigma^{2} ), then E[Y] = Mu
2. Function f(.): Takes a scalar/vector (not a random variable) and gives a scalar/vector. In this context it is an affine function, that is f(X) = a*X + b where a and b are fixed constants.

## What's Going On

Now you can view linear regression from two angles.

### Stats View

One angle assumes that your response variable-Y- is a normally distributed random variable because:

Y ~ a*X + b + epsilon

where

epsilon ~ N( 0 , sigma^sq )

and X is some other distribution. We don't really care how X is distributed and treat it as given. In that case the conditional distribution is

Y|X ~ N( a*X + b , sigma^sq )

Notice here that a,b **and also** X is a number, there is no randomness associated with them.

### Maths View

The other view is the math view where I assume that there is a function f(.) that governs the real life process, that if in real life I observe X, then f(X) should be the output. Of course this is not the case and the deviations are assumed to be due to various reasons such as gauge error etc. The claim is that this function is linear:
f(X) = a*X + b

### Synthesis

Now how do we combine these? Well, as follows:
E[Y|X] = a*X + b = f(X)

About your question, I first would like to challenge that it should be Y|X and not Y by itself.

Second, there are tons of possible ontological discussions over what each term here represents in real life. X,Y (uppercase) could be vectors. X,Y (uppercase) could also be random variables. A sample of these random variables might be stored in vectors and both would be represented with uppercase letters (the best way is to use different fonts for each). In this case, your sample will become your data. Discussions about the general view of the model and its relevance to real life should be made at random variable level. The way to infer the parameters, how linear regression algorithms works should be made at matrix and vectors levels. There could be other discussion where you should care about both.

I hope this overly unorganized answer helps you. In general if you want to learn such stuff, be sure you know what kind of math objects and operators you are dealing with , what do they take as input and what are their relevance to real life.